# How to use non-blocking HTTP requests in Mulesoft 4 Custom Connector

Tags: java, http, mule4, mule-sdk

I'm trying to build a Mulesoft custom connector which makes HTTP requests to a third-party system, and I'd like these HTTP requests to be made in a non-blocking manner such that execution can continue without waiting on the HTTP response to be returned.

There is an example of this in the Mulesoft documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/non-blocking-operations) which shows this example code:

```
public void request(String url, @Connection HttpClient client, @Content String body, 
    CompletionCallback<InputStream, HttpAttributes> callback ) { 
 client.send(url, body, new HttpResponseCallback() {
   void onResponse(HttpResponse response) {
     callback.success(Result.<InputStream, HttpAttributes>builder() 
                          .output(response.getBody())
                          .attributes(toAttributes(response))
                          .build());
   }

   void onError(Exception e) {
     callback.error(e); 
   }
 });
}
```

It also states that non-blocking behaviour can be provided

> by an HttpClient that supports asynchronous responses

[Mulesoft's custom connector documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/HTTP-based-connectors) states

> The HttpClient is capable of using non-blocking I/O to make the requests.

but I don't understand how!

The example code above calls a method `send(String, String, HttpResponseCallback)` from the `HttpClient` interface. However, the `HttpClient` interface, as documented in  [Mulesoft's API javadoc](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/4.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/runtime/http/api/client/HttpClient.html) does not have such a method.

I see that the `HttpClient` interface does have `sendAsync(HttpRequest request)` methods, but I'm failing to understand how that could be used with the example code.

I understand that Mulesoft's `HttpClient` is implemented using Project Grizzly's HTTP client, and that supports non-blocking requests, so I feel this is possible to do, I just don't understand how...

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

Hi was trying to achieve the same thing, with the same [non-blocking-operations](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/non-blocking-operations) documentation, but I wasn't able, So I try based on the
[Slack connector](https://github.com/mulesoft/slack-connector), it has a lot of examples there, and they use other code to achieve async calls [ChannelOperations with CompletionCallback](https://github.com/mulesoft/slack-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mule/extension/slack/internal/operations/ChannelOperations.java)

However, this did not work for me, I think maybe I have to make another workaround on the server-side to achieve async calls.
Anyway, In the end, I use CompletableFuture to run the request in other thread,
the request is in sync way but is performed Async in the CompletableFuture.runAsync

```js
public void request(String url, @Connection HttpClient client, @Content String body) { 

HttpResponse response = null;
HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayHttpEntity(body.toString().getBytes());
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.builder().uri(url).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .method("POST").entity(entity).build();
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
 try {
            client.start();
            response = client.send(httpRequest, 30000, true, null);
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
                LOGGER.error(response.toString());
        }
    LOGGER.info(response.toString());
        client.stop();
    
    LOGGER.info("Finish");
});
}
```

There is a Mule connector similar to [DMI](https://www.ioconnectservices.com/product/datadog-mule-integration) where the calls are made async